# Using dup2 or similar to redirect a file handle

Tags: windows, handle, dup2

Give a process in process explorer I can find the handles that process has; or indeed given a filename I can find if any processes have handles to those files.

If I understand correctly dup2 can be used to replace a file handle ie. instead of the handle pointing at file *xyz.abc* I can point it to *qwe.abc*. First off - is this correct?

Next question, assuming the above *is* correct, what is the simplest way of doing this as a complete novice? Is there a program or command line I can run that will just do it for me?

Comment: The C runtime in Windows provides a "low I/O" layer that wraps file handles with 'file descriptors' for use with POSIX functions such as `dup2` -- but this is just a with-process compatibility layer to facilitate cross-platform C code. In Windows, kernel handles can be duplicated using `DuplicateHandle`, which calls the system function `NtDuplicateObject`. NT only allows duping to an unused, arbitrary handle value in the target process. It doesn't allow replacing an existing reference to some other kernel object (not necessarily a File -- maybe an Event, Job, Process, Section, etc).

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the info! It seems like I might be able to get the desired behaviour if I open a second handle to the file (with write access) and then modify the file to be the contents of the second file (using example from question - get write access handle to xyz.abc using NtDuplicateObject, making contents of xyz.abc = contents of qwe.abc -  basically write all bytes). Does that seem possible to you? If so my next question is... how do I do this from vb.net?

Comment: Why don't you try to open "xyz.abc" an rewrite it? Anyway, if you have `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` access to the process, then you can duplicate one of its handles using WinAPI `DuplicateHandle`. The duped handle cannot get additional access to the File object. The source handle must already have the required write access. Also, don't assume it's a synchronous-mode File object, and don't mess with its file pointer; use `lpOverlapped` to explicitly set an offset of 0 for the data written via `WriteFile`. Either way, rewriting an in-use file is fragile; expect data corruption or misbehavior.